# I need to write a python code to accept number from user and convert it to binary without using functions or bin?

Tags: python

Decimal to binary in Python

I did this code and I am getting a zero(0) at the end of the answer I don't want that zero

```
num=int(input("Enter a number:"))
a=0
a=str(a)
while num>0:
    a=a+str(num%2)
    num=int(num/2)
print(a[::-1],end='')
```

My Output :
Enter a number:42
1010100

I don't need the final zero
I need

Enter a number:42
101010

Comment: Hey Little_One, the answers provided by DanielAaron and mackorone should right away solve your problem. However, it seems to me, that you are new to programming and I figure that you maybe want to learn new stuff, so:
 1. try using masking instead of modulo operation: `str(num & 1)` vs `str(num%2)`
 2. try using bit shifting instead of division `num = num >> 1` vs `num = int(num / 2)`
 3. try building your string a in reverse order, so that you don't have to reverse it in the end: `a = str(num & 1) + a`

Answer (score 2):

A better formation:

```py
num = int(input("Enter a number: "))
a = ''
while num > 0:
    a += str(num % 2)
    num //= 2
print(a[::-1])
```

```
Enter a number: 42
101010
```

As a beginner, you should pay attention to your programming habits to make your code more concise and readable.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! Can you explain to me what's the difference between the two codes :)

Answer (score 1):

Set `a=""` and remove a=str(a) should solve your issue

Answer (score 1):

Rather than initialize `a` to `"0"`, just initialize it to the empty string:

```
num=int(input("Enter a number:"))
a=""
while num>0:
    a=a+str(num%2)
    num=int(num/2)
print(a[::-1],end='')
```